# Why is React updating state even though I'm not updating the state using useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I was always under the assumption that React updates the UI only when I make immutable changes to the state. Recently I came across a snippet that did something I didn't expect:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [strings, setStrings] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          strings[strings.length] = e.target.value;
          setInputValue(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <ul>
        {strings.map((s) => {
          return <li>{s}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I expected that the list would not update when I enter values in input, as I am making mutable changes to the `strings` variable, and as React uses object references to compare and update the DOM, there would be no changes in the list.

But the list updates whenever there's a change in the input.

The same lists will not update if I define the `strings` variable as a normal javascript array and not as React state:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  // const [strings, setStrings] = useState<string[]>([]);
  let strings: string[] = [];
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          strings[strings.length] = e.target.value;
          setInputValue(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <ul>
        {strings.map((s) => {
          return <li>{s}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Looks like my understanding of how React updates and compares states and js variables between virtual doms is lacking, please help!

How exactly does React compare the states? I am under the assumption that it is using the [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) method underneath to compare objects, in which case, how does it know that the state changed when I am keeping the object reference same?

[CodeSandbox Repo](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/codesandbox/codesandbox-template-vite-react/csb-zgm30c/draft/gifted-sunset?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A41%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A14%2C%22startColumn%22%3A41%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A14%7D%5D) for your reference.

Edit: I know that I am forcing a re-render with the line `setInputValue(e.target.value);`, but I am essentially trying to understand how exactly React compares states when it is re-rendering. How would React know that `strings` state has changed without its object reference changing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are updating the state with the `setInputValue` call, so React rerenders your component (and it therefore sees the updated version of `strings`). So the first example is working only by accident, because you change another state at the same place.

The second example doesn't work because the `strings` variable is reset at each new render.

Comment: (Repeating my comment from the other answer) Sorry, please look at the edit for the question. I knew that the UI was being updated because of the setInputValue, but I didn't understand why React has not ignored the update to the strings state when its object reference has not changed.

Comment: It cannot ignore part of the state. Either it rerenders or it doesn't, and if it rerenders then it uses the whole new state because that's simply how functions work in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your code. the React re-render because the `inputValue` changed.
You can try to only mutate `strings` in your `onChange` code without `setInputValue`, and it should not re-render as before.

Comment: Sorry, please look at the edit for the question. I knew that the UI was being updated because of the `setInputValue`, but I didn't understand why React has not ignored the update to the `strings` state when its object reference has not changed.

Comment: @TejaBalu Because React will re-run the function `App` and get its output (which is  ReactElement), so the changed `strings` state will have real effect in the React Element.

Comment: @TejaBalu React update Application in an App-level, which means every time state change will trigger the whole  app re-render from root to bottom. I guess you are thinking about some concept like [`Signal`](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/signals/) in Preact or similiar things in Svelet, which acts atomically to the state level change.

Comment: Or you are mixuring the concept of `diff` and `render`?  The scenario you faced has nothing to do with `diff`, because React didn't notice the change in `strings`. But React still render the `strings` newset value, because React render the whole app tree when any state changed. You can try to  create a `setInterval` in `useEffect` to push anything into `strings` in `strings.push` way, and you can see the React doesnt' re-render as `strings.push` happens, but after you input anything (`setInputValue`), the  dom will change and display the newsest `strings`

Comment: Yes, I'm slightly confused about React rendering using all the new states. I knew that changing a state triggers a rerender, but while it does that, I assumed it only cherry-picks the states that have differed from the previous render and creates a new render with those changes alone.

Comment: @TejaBalu Surely it is a way, and  somehow used by the `Preact` and `Svelet`,  while `React ` choose to render all thing at once ~

Comment: @TejaBalu Wait a minute, I fond I may make a mistake: the `React` may do notice the change happened, because  the  children `li` in `ul` inside the React Element   actually grow, so React will mark and  create  dom insert action. My apologies.

Comment: `state` changed trigger `re-render` (this is only due to `setInputValue`), and then compare the output `ReactElement` with elder `fiberNode` ( `virtual-dom diff`), and then realize diff(including the `li` children grows) and  mark updates.

Comment: No, I had the same doubt that React was maybe updating because I was adding additional `<li>` tags but that didn't work too. I rendered the `strings` object under a single `<p>` tag and I have the same result where the <`p>` tag displays and updates all the array values.

Comment: But thanks on letting me know that React updates the states of all of the descendants no matter if the states have changed or not. I guess I'll have to integrate that into my mental model of how React works.